# End of line character missing with capture.output in R

Tags: r

In R, when I print/cat in a function, it is printed properly in stdout when the function is called. When I put the output in a variable via capture.output, the end-of-line character "\n" is missing.

*Here is simple R code example:*

```
ff <- function(){ print(-5:-1);cat("dummy line\n");print(1:5)}
ff()
```

gives the output:

```
[1] -5 -4 -3 -2 -1
dummy line
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

and the following code gives output in single line.

```
ff_out<-capture.output(ff())
ff_out
```

gives the same output in one line (i.e., with "\n" missing)

I must be missing something very simple. Please help me resolve this to get the same output as shown above.

Comment: Nice first question: concise, reproducible example, formatted. Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not actually "in one line". It's a vector of length three, where each element is one of the lines. You can

```
cat(ff_out, sep="\n")

# [1] -5 -4 -3 -2 -1
# dummy line
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

To inspect an object, `str` is useful, like

```
str(ff_out)
#  chr [1:3] "[1] -5 -4 -3 -2 -1" "dummy line" "[1] 1 2 3 4 5"
```

The part at the start indicates that it is a character vector of length three.

Comment: The # comment at the start of output lines is standard on stackoverflow for R.

Comment: Thanks [Frank](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1191259/frank) with the solution. That answers my question. Very much appreciated.